# Need to resolve com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: junit, datasource, sql-server-2014-express

I am using JUnit for test my application. 
    In my application I used DataSource to get connection with database. All database connection properties I am getting from context.xml
    So while testing with Junit, i had written code to initialize InitialContext and set database properties in the DataSource, 
    But while getting connection I am getting the login failed error. 
    I don't know why it is happening, please let me know how to resolve all these issues.

```
# For initialization i had written #
// Create initial context
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, 
            "org.apache.naming");            
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

        ic.createSubcontext("java:");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:comp");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:comp/env");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:comp/env/jdbc");

        // Construct DataSource
        SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource();

        ds.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=database");
        ds.setUser("sa");
        ds.setPassword("*****");
        ic.bind("java:comp/env/jdbc/devTEST", ds);



 // Code for  getting connection it is written in another class


Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/dev" + dbEnv.toUpperCase());
connection = ds.getConnection();
```

---

Issue is when i get DataSource object from initial context object then all database connection properties are there in Datasource object but password was missing so  I am getting exeception while creating Connection of database

Comment: It's happening most probably because you passed the wrong user, the wrong password, or both.

Comment: I passed correct username and password, but the problem is when i DataSource creating connection at that time it don't have the password to create connection. I checked the object properties, only username is present and password is missing. So don't know where the password lost while reading it from context object